# How do I modify the diameter of a circle on an imported .obj file

Tags: mesh

I have a F360 drawing I imported to Blender 2.9
I have a hole all the way through the item which is 2mm diameter
I want to modify the hole to 1.5mm diameter.
Thank you for any ideas or tips.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the MeasureIt addon turned on?